# Algorithm for maintaining an "ordering string" for ordering database elements

Tags: database, algorithm, google-app-engine

I have a database in which I'd like to store an arbitrary ordering for a particular element. The database in question doesn't support order sets, so I have to do this myself.

One way to do this would be to store a float value for the element's position, and then take the average of the position of the surrounding elements when inserting a new one:

```
Item A - Position 1
Item B - Position 1.5  (just inserted).
Item C - Position 2
```

Now, for various reasons I don't wish to use floats, I'd like to use strings instead.  For example:

```
Item A - Position a
Item B - Position aa  (just inserted).
Item C - Position b
```

I'd like to keep these strings as short as possible since they will never be "tidied up".

Can anyone suggest an algorithm for generating such string as efficiently and compactly as possible?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: If your next item is to be ordered between Items A and B (at a position between 'a' and 'aa') what ordering string would you assign to it ?

Comment: Good question :) I'd like an algorithm that would always allow me to insert a value, unlike in the example above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be reasonable to assign 'am' or 'an' position to Item B and use binary division steps for another insertions.
This resembles 26-al number system, where 'a'..'z' symbols correspond to 0..25.

```
a b   //0 1
a an b  //insert after a  - middle letter of alphabet  
a an au b  //insert after an
a an ar au b  //insert after an again (middle of an, au)
a an ap ar au b   //insert after an again
a an ao ap ar au b //insert after an again
a an ann ao...  //insert after an, there are no more place after an, have to use 3--symbol label
....
a an anb...  //to insert after an, we treat it as ana
a an anan anb  // it looks like 0 0.5 0.505 0.51
```

Pseudocode for binary tree structure:

```
function InsertAndGetStringKey(Root, Element): string
  if Root = nil then
    return Middle('a', 'z') //'n'

  if Element > Root then
    if Root.Right = nil then
      return Middle(Root.StringKey, 'z') 
    else
       return InsertAndGetStringKey(Root.Right, Element)   

  if Element < Root then
    if Root.Left = nil then
      return Middle(Root.StringKey, 'a') 
    else
       return InsertAndGetStringKey(Root.Left, Element) 

Middle(x, y): 
  //equalize length of strings like (an, anf)-> (ana, anf)
  L = Length(x) - Length(y)
  if L < 0 then
    x = x + StringOf('a', -L) //x + 'aaaaa...' L times
  else if L > 0 then
    y = y + StringOf('a', L)  

  if LL = LastSymbol(x) - LastSymbol(y)  = +-1 then
    return(Min(x, y) + 'n')  // (anf, ang) - > anfn
  else
    return(Min(x, y) + (LastSymbol(x) + LastSymbol(y))/2) // (nf, ni)-> ng
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm being blind, but if you keep inserting after "an" you'll end up with "a an ana anb anc ...". How do you now insert between an and ana?

Comment: My head's spinning :) In the first case you managed to insert between "an" and "ao" by adding "ann". In the second case to insert between "an" and "anb" we can't use "ana" but we have to move to 4 characters.   I feel like the algorithm itself is slipping around the sides of my head and refuses to enter.

Comment: @MBo seems to be offering floating-point numbers in base 26 !

Comment: Ah, of course. So when comparing "an" to "anb" we really need to compare strings of the same length ("ana" to "anb"). "ana" is the same as "an" in the same way that 0.5 is the same as 0.50. "a" is essentially 0. Nice solution. Would anyone care to suggest some pseudo-code? :)

Comment: @tarmes Do the first pair of elements determine full range for all another element keys?

Comment: There's no limit to the range - I should be able to add items to the end of the list at any time if that's what you mean?

Comment: I've marked the answer as correct because the idea of using floating point numbers in base 26 is clearly a winning strategy. However I can't follow your pseudo code - what's needed is a way to generate the string key that fit's between to other string keys - you're code appears to be doing something different, although I'm not sure what. What's Root?

Comment: Added middle string generation (rough sketch).  'Insert' code finds a place for insertion of new element - don't know it is needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

As stated the problem has no solution. Once an algorithm has generated strings 'a' and 'aa' for adjacent elements there is no string which can be inserted between them.  This is a fatal problem for the approach.  This problem is independent of the alphabet used for the strings: replace 'a' by 'the first letter in the alphabet used' if you wish.

Of course, it can be worked around by changing the ordering string for other elements when this impasse is reached, but that seems to be beyond what OP wants.

I think that the problem is equivalent to finding an integer to represent the order of an element and finding that, say, 35 and 36 are already used to order existing elements.  There is simply no integer between 35 and 36, no matter how hard you look.

Use real numbers, or a computer approximation such as floating-point numbers, or rationals.

**EDIT** in response to OP's comment

Just adapt the algorithm for adding 2 rationals: (a/b)+(c/d) = (ad+cb)/bd.  Take (ad+cb)/2 (rounding if you want or need) and you have a rational midway between the first two.

Comment: Rationals sound interesting, however I can't see how to create such an algorithm - do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Are capitals an option?

If so, I would use them to insert between otherwise adjacent values.

For instance to insert between
a
aa

You could do:

a

aAaa  <--- this cap. tells there is one more place between adjacent small values .ie. a[Aa]a

aAba

aAca

aBaa

aBba

aa

Now if you need to insert between a and aAaa

You could do

a

aAAaaa  <--- 2 caps. tells there are two more places between adjacent small values i.e. a[AAaa]a

aAAaba

aAAaca

...

aAAbaa

aAaa

In terms of being compact or efficient I make no claims...

Comment: I don't really follow you, however it seems that inserting between a and aa would give you "a aAaa aa", which when fetched by the database would be in the wrong order.